# scrolldown layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I'm developing an Android app and I want to do animation like the Path app in the timeline.

When the user `scrollTop`, the image (cover image) will have elasticity. And on `scrollDown`, it will load content (like `listview`). Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I really don't get your question. Im gonna take a wild guess! Are you talking about Pull to refresh pattern in android? [check here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=121315)

Comment: Hi prijupaul. No, It's mean not Pull to refressh. But like same. Image will show but a half. When user scroll, it's will elasticity full. ! !

Comment: Basically you need to have a cutom ImageView here. You need to extend ImageView and include this class in your xml file. Later, you also need to extend onTouchListener and override, onTouch. In onTouch, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, you need to increase the height of the ImageView, (using getLayoutParams and SetLayoutParams). In ACTION_UP, you need to assign the layout params back to original.

Comment: Hi Prijupaul. Thanks for sugesstion. I will try and hope it's good for me. thank you again ! ! !

Comment: Did you get this done or do you want me to post some code? I just tried a sample app and I got it working. Lemme know. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Prijupaul. I tried but it not working. Can you help me ? Thank so much. I can't using scoll up in motionEvent.

Comment: Hi @Prijupaul: Can you help me about this !

Comment: Sorry.. Was held up with other things. Shall post the code later. Dont have it with me now. The idea is same as Pull to refresh code.

Comment: Hi there, I have created a sample app. Check this link. https://github.com/prijupaul/Priju/tree/master/ImageStrecher. Appreciate if you accept the ans if it helped. Thnx

Comment: Appreciate if you could please mark this as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @prijupaul. I don't know ? I can't mark for your answer ? I can't found arrow

Comment: There will be a tick mark next to the answer, when you have logged in. Just tick that mark to say its accepted! :)